# CodedUITest - Parameterize WinTreeItem object in WinTree object.

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a `WinTree` object which consists of three `WinTreeItem` objects. The problem I have is that I need to parameterize the first `WinTreeItem`(root) so I can select 1st, 2nd, or 3rd `WinTreeItem`.

Here is the code where I have the `WinTree` object which has the `WitTreeItem` name as a property.

```
public class UITree1Tree : WinTree
{

    public UITree1Tree(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
            base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinTree.PropertyNames.Name] = "Tree Lists:";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Insert Symbol List");
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public UITrSymbolLiTreeItem UITradeStationSymbolLiTreeItem
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUITrSymbolLiTreeItem == null))
            {
                this.mUITrSymbolLiTreeItem = new UITrSymbolLiTreeItem(this);
            }
            return this.mUITrSymbolLiTreeItem;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private UITrSymbolLiTreeItem mUITrSymbolLiTreeItem;
    #endregion
}

public class UITrSymbolLiTreeItem: WinTreeItem
{

    public UITrSymbolLiTreeItem (UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
            base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinTreeItem.PropertyNames.Name] = "Tr Symbol Lists";
        this.SearchProperties["Value"] = "0";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Insert Tr List");
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your question, but would the [GetChildren()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.getchildren.aspx) method work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Constructor of the class to pass the parameter.

OR

Add a Property to its parent and set this Property while initializing. The Parent testcontrol will be available inside child and hence your parameter also available. You can use this parameter inside the child wherever you want.

I did in this way through out my project and it works fine.